# wordpress image loading

Tags: jquery, image, loading

I want to add that spinning wheel image effect while loading all my images in wordpress using jquery. If there is a lot of images its ugly to see he images loading slowly, so I need them to show the loading.gif while loading.

What is the best way to achieve this? Also can I choose this feature only on the css classes that I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you cand do like this

```
background: url('loading.gif') center no-repeat;
```

Comment: I mentioned jquery because it will look a lot better if they load one at a time. And the way you mentioned looks terrible simple. but i will try it anyway

Comment: Actually this is the bg image of the container element of your image. Afetr the image loads you are not going to see anymore the bg of the container.